# How to change the Class Prefix in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

When creating a project in Xcode 4, it asks what Class prefix to add to all new files.

Is there a way to change (or remove) this, after a project is already started?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In Xcode 4.3 at least it is persistent.  To change it click on your project then in the right hand menu there is an option to change it.  If you don't have the right hand menu open hit the button up at the top to make it appear.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

To add class prefix or change prefix for a project

[image]

While adding new files to the project, we get the filename with the prefix where we can append the rest of the filename.

[image]

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 6):

***Outdated Answer*** - Recent versions use this prefix for all new classes now.

> This only affects the files created from a *project template* when you
>   create a new project. It's not a persistent setting and has no affect
>   when creating new files.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Don't know why I thought that. =)

Comment: Maybe you read the same things I did - the complaints about no name spaces in Objective-C. It's what made *me* think this prefix option was a persistent thing. I reasoned Apple was trying to make it easier to keep consistent with class name prefixes as a bandaid. But then I couldn't find the setting anywhere (and a string search of the project file didn't turn it up either).

Comment: See Odyth's response (+1). It's now the correct response. Prior to 4.3, only the files created from project templates were graced by the chosen class prefix. 4.3 and greater now use this prefix pervasively.

Comment: I've changed the correct answer, but up-voted Joshua's as his was the correct response at the time.